# angle data from eigen MatrixXcd

Tags: c++, arrays, numbers, eigen

I am working with the EIGEN 3.2 c++ Matrix library.  I have a problem that requires my extracting the phase or angle information from a matrix of type Eigen::MatrixXcd.  The problem involves my having a matrix of complex numbers that is the result of calculations in my code.  I have the result M of dimension nsamp by nsamp where nsamp is an integer of size 256 (for example).

Hence, MatrixXcd  M(nsamp, nsamp);

Now I want to extract the phase (or angle information) from M.  I know that the complex analysis method of doing this is,

MatrixXcd ratio = M.imag().array().sin()/M.real().array().cos(); 
MatrixXd phase  = M.real().array().atan();

However, there is no atan method in the Eigen library.  So, as a work around I am using

MatrixXcd cosPhase = M.real().array().cos()/M.array().abs(); 
MatrixXd phase     = M.real().array().acos();

The math is solid, but I am getting incorrect answers.  I have looked at the imaginary component i.e.

MatrixXd phase     = M.imag().array().acos();

and get answers that are "more correct," which does not make sense.

Has anyone in the community dealt with this before and what is your solution?

Many Thanks,

Robert

Answer (score 2):

Well.  For anyone seeing this.  I figured out the answer to my own question.  To calculate the phase contribution we need to calculate the phase using the 2*atan(imag/(sqrt(real^2+imag^2)+real)) algorithm.
This is some simple test code included using the armadillo library

```css
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // calculate the phase content resulting from a complex field 
    // matrix of type Eigen::MatrixXcd  
    double pi = acos(-1);
    mat phase(2,2);
    phase << pi/2 <<  pi/2 << endr
             pi/2 <<  pi/2 << endr;
    
    // form the complex field
    cx_mat complexField = cx_mat(cos(phase), sin(phase));
    
    // calculate the phase using the tan2 identity
    mat REAL = real(complexField);
    mat IMAG = imag(complexField);

    // calculate the phase using real component of complexField
    mat phaseResult = 2*atan(IMAG/(sqrt(REAL%REAL+IMAG%IMAG)+REAL));
    cout << phaseResult << "\n" << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Very likely the function did not exist at the time the question was asked, but the simplest solution is to call the [`arg()`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#a0ecf327d063adcac1e9b6bda145920bb) function.

```
Eigen::MatrixXcd mat = ...;
Eigen::MatrixXd phase = mat.array().arg(); // needs .array() since this works per element
```

If you ever need to calculate this manually, better use `atan2(imag, real)` instead of that complicated `2*atan(...)` formula.